# Get all roles under current users role

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to get all the roles under the current logged in users role.
We dont know the levels in the hierarchy, it would change depending on the logged in user.

Any pointers on how we can achieve this on a generic way

```
  currentUserRoleId= userInfo.getUserRoleId();
```

I want to see all the roles under currentUserRoleId and the roles under each level.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a pre-built way to do this. However, you should be able to write code to do it recursively like so:

```
public static set<Id> getSubordinateRoles(Id roleId) {
    map<Id, set<Id>> parentAndChildren = new map<Id, set<Id>>();
    set<Id> children;
    for(UserRole ur : [select Id, ParentRoleId from UserRole]) {
        children = parentAndChildren.containsKey(ur.ParentRoleId) ? parentAndChildren.get(ur.ParentRoleId) : new set<Id>();
        children.add(ur.Id);
        parentAndChildren.put(ur.ParentRoleId, children);
    }
    return getSubordinateRoles(role, parentAndChildren);
}

public static set<Id> getSubordinateRoles(Id roleId, map<Id, set<Id>> parentAndChildren) {
    set<Id> subordinateRoles = new set<Id>();
    set<Id> remainingSubordinateRoles = new set<Id>();
    if(parentAndChildren.containsKey(roleId)) {
        subordinateRoles.addAll(parentAndChildren.get(roleId));
        for(Id subRoleId : subordinateRoles) {
            remainingSubordinateRoles.addAll(getSubordinateRoles(subRoleId, parentAndChildren));
        }
    }
    subordinateRoles.addAll(remainingSubordinateRoles);
    return subordinateRoles;
}
```

I haven't tested this, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @TriangleMan , In  your code whereever you are mentioning as role should be RoleId isnt it? I am getting an variable not found error.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Triangle Man  .. It worked like charm. One more thing return subordinateRoles.addAll(remainingSubordinateRoles); was throwing an error saying it should return only a Set<id> . I made the addAll statement in one line and returned subordinateRoles. That worked fine after that.

Comment: @Prady Thanks for the catch, I always forget that the Apex .add and .addAll methods return void. I've changed the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks once again for your help :)